# Google Calendar API, missing event notifications

Tags: google-calendar-api

We've come across a strange issue whereby *sometimes* we don't receive push notifications or even receive event info during a sync about an added event to a calendar until we log into Google Calendar and view the calendar. Then push notifications come through, literally just logging into GC causes the events to fire. Anyone else seen this or have any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   Without seeing your code we cant help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it looks extremely likely it is due to the new European privacy settings Gmail have started to enable on EU accounts very recently.

The events we were missing were events that were added through the processing of gmail emails that contained event invites (ICS).

See: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10079371?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en